# WiX Installer not building on Windows 10

Tags: wix, windows-installer, windows-10

I am having trouble with getting a merge module to build in VS2013 on Windows 10 Enterprise. From searching around all day it seems to be related to not having .Net3.5 installed.

I’ve tried all the different ways suggested but .Net3.5 just won’t install on my system and there are a lot of people who seem to have the same issue.

My actual WiX error message is as follows;

```
Error      1              The "CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v4.0\bin\WixTasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v4.0\bin\wix.targets               709
```

I started using v3.8 which we use on other projects but also have the same issue with v3.10, v3.11 and v4.0.

Does anyone know if WiX still has a dependency on .Net3.5 and if any of the later unstable versions are dropping this?

I tried joining and sending an email to the WiX Installer Email forum but my question is never posted and there is very little ability to figure out why. I do get various email question from others so I know I have joined the group. Is there a better forum for community questions? The email group approach seems rather out dated today.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: I was getting the same issue on a Windows 10 PC, with Visual Studio 2015 and a .NET Framework 2.0 project. In the end, I learned how to (easily) use candle.exe and light.exe, so I'm editing the _wxs_ file with Notepad++, and using a Command Prompt to create the MSI file.

Answer (score 0):

WiX 4.0 is very experimental and not meant for production use at this time.  Go back to the latest stable release of WiX 3.xx that you can find.  Don't use a weekly release in production.

I seem to remember a bug on this but don't know for sure.  I'd install .NET 2.0/3.5 for now.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really looking to use 4.0 just more seeing if it resolved my issue. Problem is I just can't get .NET 2.0/3.5 installed on my system!! None of the methods work and I've tried several variations of each. Beginning to think I need a clean install.